# javascript empty array inside an object

Tags: javascript, object

I've got an object like this:

```
var obj = {
    age:["23"],
    part:["0"],
    race:[],
    state:["AL"],
    gender:["1"],
    county:["9999"],
    consent:["9999"]
};
```

I pass this object to php for processing, but `race[]` is not passed to php along with everything else. How do I change `race` so it gets sent and has a value of `""`?

#### EDIT: Any one of those (age, part, race, …) could be empty, so I need a way to check and then change.

I've used this code to loop thru the object/array: http://jsfiddle.net/jshado1/wLZMH/

Comment: Did you try `obj.race = [""];`?

Comment: How are you passing it to PHP? Also, is there any reason why all of your object values are 1-length arrays?

Comment: @fluffy: via jQuery AJAX. Race can have multiple values, ex `race:["asian","black","white"]`

Comment: It's normal for the jQuery parameter serialiser (and browsers in general) to omit unfilled fields - you should fix your PHP script to anticipate that.

Comment: I wrote my own serialiser because I needed more complex output.

Comment: @jacob Okay, and they can have multiple ages and states of residence? (Also what's with "1" for gender?)

Comment: @fluffy They can't have multiple ages or states of residence, but there are many, many more questions, and many of them (say, where of the following do you frequent) can have multiple answers. I didn't get to choose the code for the values, but I think 1 is male.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
if(obj.race!==undefined && obj.race.length===0){
   obj.race = [""];
}
```

Or:

```
if(obj.race!==undefined && obj.race.length===0){
   obj.race.push("");
}
```

EDIT:

For all elements

```
for(var key in obj){
 if(obj[key]!==undefined && obj[key].length===0){
     obj[key] = [""];
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! btw when I wrote it, I had `obj[key].length < 1` and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you've marked it up in that way. If you're passing key–value pairs to PHP, then it should look as follows:

```
var obj = {
    age: "23",
    part: "0",
    race: {
        "Value 1",
        "Value 2"
    },
    state: "AL",
    gender: "1",
    county: "9999",
    consent: "9999"
};
```

That way, each value would be passed to PHP (as it's a string, despite being empty).

Comment: they are arrays because `race` could have multiple values.

Comment: You'd probably be better passing an object rather than an array then, as modified above.

Comment: Functionally, what's the difference between this and the array I have?

Comment: Arrays are for numerically indexed data, objects are for non-numeric keys. Plus, objects are more extendable.

Comment: Ah okay. So what is `age:"23"` in your example and what is `race: {"value 1","value 2"}` (are they both objects)?

Comment: No. "23" is a string, as it's surrounded by quotes (it probably should be an integer). The value for `race` is an object, as it's wrapped in curly braces ('{' and '}').